# How to make an Excel instance visible if there are no open workbooks using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hidden, multiple-instances, visible

I have several instances of Excel running, maybe up to 4 instances.  One of these (let's call in instance A) usually does not have an open workbook.  It is used by one of the other instances (let's call it instance B) to open a workbook in instance A, add, change data, then save and close that workbook, thus the instance where these changes are being made (instance A) returns to a state where there are no open workbooks.  I do it this way because it is much faster than having the workbook with the code (instance B) open a workbook, perform these tasks and then close the workbook.

My problem is this: From time to time, for debugging purposes mostly, it is desirable to make instance A visible, but what I'm finding is that an instance without an open workbook cannot be made visible, or at least this is what I'm concluding. I am using Excel 2016, 64 bit.  My code to do this is:

```
Private Sub cmdMakeSelectionVisible_Click()


Dim strng As String
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application
Dim bFoundInstance As Boolean
Dim wb_Actress As Workbook

With Me.lstXL '<--| refer to your listbox: change "ListBox1" with your actual listbox name
    For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1 '<--| loop through listbox rows
        If .Selected(lRow) Then '<--| if current row selected
            For lCol = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1 '<--| loop through listbox columns
                strng = strng & .List(lRow, lCol) & " | " '<--| build your output string

                If lCol = 1 Then
                    MsgBox .List(lRow, lCol)
                    bFoundInstance = GetReferenceToXLApp(.List(lRow, lCol), oXLApp)
                    MsgBox oXLApp.Caption
                    Set wb_Actress = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("T:\-1996\Dummy Performer's Book.xlsm")
                    oXLApp.Visible = True
                    wb_Actress.Close
                End If

            Next lCol
            MsgBox "you selected" & vbCrLf & Left(strng, (Len(strng) - 1)) '<--| show output string (after removing its last character ("|"))
            Exit For '<-_| exit loop
        End If
    Next lRow
End With
End Sub
```

Inside the For Loops there is an If statement and in that If statement if the instance in question opens a workbook, then the code works.  If the instance does not open a workbook and it contains no children, it does not work.  If at that point I test to see if oXApp.Visible is true, it is true, but the instance remains hidden.

The question is, is there any way around this without opening a workbook, make the instance visible, then closing the workbook?  I still consider myself a novice when it comes to VBA.  There may be a totally different approach other than using the handle to the desired instance.

Thanks for looking and helping.

Edit:

The code for GetReferenceToXLApp is:

```
    Public Function GetReferenceToXLApp(hWndXL As Long, oXLApp As Object) As Boolean

Dim hWinDesk         As Long
Dim hWin7            As Long

Dim obj              As Object
Dim iID              As GUID

'// Rather than explaining, go read
'// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687262(v=vs.85).aspx
Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iID)

'// We have the XL App (Class name XLMAIN)
'// This window has a child called 'XLDESK' (which I presume to mean 'XL desktop')
'// XLDesk is the container for all XL child windows....
hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWndXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)

'// EXCEL7 is the class name for a Workbook window (and probably others, as well)
'// This is used to check there is actually a workbook open in this instance.
hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)

'// Deep API... read up on it if interested.
'// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx
If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iID, obj) = RETURN_OK Then
    Set oXLApp = obj.Application
    GetReferenceToXLApp = True
End If

End Function
```

And

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
(ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
```

And

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
```

Comment: What does `GetReferenceToXLApp`. do? Please include that code in your question...

Comment: It also matters which version of Excel you have. If you have one of the newer versions, then they use SDI instead of MDI

Comment: @braX - you can still create multiple instances: eg. hold down Alt while launching Excel from the Taskbar via a right-click.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work...

```
Dim oApp As Excel.Application


Sub TT()

    Set oApp = New Excel.Application
    'oApp.Workbooks.Add
    oApp.Visible = True

    Debug.Print oApp.HWnd, Application.HWnd
    Debug.Print oApp.Caption, Application.Caption

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
    AppActivate Application.Caption

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
    AppActivate oApp.Caption

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am not getting it to make the new instance visible unless I un-comment the line ...  oApp.Workbooks.Add.  If I un-comment this line, then oApp.Visible = True works and the last line works.  If I run the code just as you have it here, the Visible line does nothing (no eror though) and I get an error at the last line, Error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument.  If this works on your end then I am wondering if an add-in on my end is not the culprit.  I don't really run add-ins, but I know some are checked.

Comment: I have determined that KUTools has something to do with the problem.  If I disable it, everything works fine including my original code as presented here.  Interestingly, if I disable it, run the code once, then re-enable it without closing any books or instances, the code still works.  Thank you Tim for pointing me in the right direction.