# Show all hidden instances of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to make visible multiple hidden instances of Excel without closing them? I know we can use `GetObject` to get a reference the the last opened instance, close it and loop to get other instances e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334862/how-to-make-an-excel-instance-visible-if-there-are-no-open-workbooks-using-vba) and we can use handles to Excel windows to the same effect but in this case I want the instances and their workbooks to remain open for the user to close at their discretion. I do not want to save the workbooks if I can help it (i.e. cache paths, close all instances, re-open workbooks), I just want to set the `.Visible` property of all Excel instances to `True`.

One way is to store the application object whenever I instance one but is there a cleaner alternative, particularly one that is agnostic of the previous stack? i.e. could be run standalone at any time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, copy next code in a new standard module:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias _
            "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, _
            ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
            ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
            (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
            (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As LongPtr, ByRef riid As GUID, _
            ByRef ppvObject As Object) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
            (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
             ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
            (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
    Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
             ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
#End If

Private Type GUID
    data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0

Function GetExcelAppCollection() As Variant
   Dim dict As Object, i As Long
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWinXL As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWinXL As Long
    #End If
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    While hWinXL > 0
        i = i + 1
        If GetXLapp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(xlApp.hwnd) Then
                dict.Add xlApp.hwnd, xlApp
            End If
        End If
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Wend
     GetExcelAppCollection = dict.items
End Function
#If VBA7 Then
    Function GetXLapp(hWinXL As LongPtr, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
    Dim hWinDesk As LongPtr, hWin7 As LongPtr
#Else
    Function GetXLapp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
    Dim hWinDesk As Long, hWin7 As Long
#End If

Dim obj As Object
Dim iid As GUID
    
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
    hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
        Set xlApp = obj.Application
        GetXLapp = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then, you can run the next sub (in the same module), able to find all open sessions and make visible the hidden ones:

```
Sub MakeSessionsVisible()
   Dim arr As Variant, El
   arr = GetExcelAppCollection
   Debug.Print UBound(arr)
   For Each El In arr
        If Not El.Visible Then El.Visible = True
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I set up an example by declaring 3 instances of Excel in Access using the Excel 16 object reference but `If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then` never returns true. What could be the problem?

Comment: `hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)` returns zero, could it be the "EXCEL7" string? I tried "Excel12" but still zero.

Comment: @Absinthe: When you say "declaring 3 instances of Excel" did you open at least a new workbook in them? If not, they will be automatically closed. You can check it looking in `TaskManager` and see how many open Excel instances you can see. Did you copy **all the code** as it is? I mean, also the constants in the module declarations area (on top of it)...

Comment: @Absinthe: I have this code from years and it worked and works as it should. I used it to enumerate all open workbooks in all Excel instances. I adapted now to show the hidden ones. Tested and it works as it should. Can you share the module where you have the code? I mean, you can select all its text and copy it... Then place it in a text file and share on a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free transfer site, easy to be used...

Comment: In order to open new instances, try using `Dim ex as Object`  `Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application"): ex.Workbooks.Add`. And then test the code. It will show the two newly created instances. It behaves in this way on my computer. I test it on Excel, but it should work on any VBA environment, if the code is exactly as the one as I posted...

Comment: @Absinthe: I've just tested the code on Corel VBA. It creates Excel instances and show all hidden ones running the code... I only change the declaration from  `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application` in `Dim xlApp As Object`, in order to avoid referencing Excel Application.

Comment: @Absinthe: Do you have Spy++? Or a similar program able to return the class of a specific window... I mean, the above code was tested on all Excel versions up to 2016 Professional and it works. What Excel version should be detected?

Comment: Like alternative to Spy++, try downloading the free WinSpy++ from [here](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy#). Try opening an Excel instance, a visible one, then open WinSpay and drag its 'target' icon over the Excel Sheet. It will return the Window handle, its Text, **Class** and something else. Is it in your case "EXCEL7"?

Comment: It was the fact my test instances did not have workbooks. Thanks.

Comment: @Absinthe: In fact, there were no such instances... Without at least an open workbook, the open instance is automatically quit...

Comment: Not so, if you declare variables for them so the ref is still around

Comment: @Absinthe: Nope, the reference is valid only inside the procedure which you create the instance. When the procedure is exited, the instance quits. Do you see them in Task Manager? If not, hey do not exist, anymore...