# How to refer to an Open Excel Workbook from PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am writing a program in PowerPoint VBA that needs data to an Excel Workbook (wbPool, with file path wbPoolPath).

When the workbook is not open my code is working but I am having trouble referencing to that workbook when it is already open.

```vb
Dim wbPool As Excel.Workbook
If isOpen(wbPoolPath) Then ' isOpen returns True if wbPool is already open, returns False if not
    Set wbPool = GetObject(wbPoolPath) ' returns wbPool = Nothing 
Else
    Set wbPool = Excel.Workbooks.Open(wbPoolPath)
End If
If wbPool Is Nothing Then GoTo ErrPoolOpen
```

`GetObject(wbPoolPath)` returns Nothing. My guess is that my company's antivirus software blocks the use of `GetObject`.

I tried two different means to replace `GetObject` with `Set wbPool`:

```vb
'Split is used to get the workbook name from its fullname
Set wbPool = Workbooks(Split(wbPoolPath, "\")(UBound(Split(wbPoolPath, "\"))))
```

&

```vb
'Loops through all workbooks until it matches with wbPool
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
For Each wb In Excel.Workbooks
    If wb.FullName = wbPoolPath Then
        Set wbPool = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
```

Both return wbPool = Nothing, while Excel.Workbooks returns "Out of context".

The antivirus software is Cylance Protect.

Comment: Use `GetObject` to get a reference to *Excel*, not to the workbook, i.e. `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`. Also, if there is no instance of Excel open, then you should create an instance programmatically.

Comment: @BigBen , i tried `Set wbPool = xlApp.Workbooks(Split(wbPoolPath, "\")(UBound(Split(wbPoolPath, "\"))))` with xlApp being `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`  is it correct ? (it is also blocked by my antivirus software, but good to know the correct use of GetObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you work on a Windows PC then the following code will get the Excel instance for a given workbook name

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
    (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
    ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
         
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0

Function getXLApp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
    Dim hWinDesk As Long, hWin7 As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim iid As GUID
    
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
    hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
        Set xlApp = obj.Application
        getXLApp = True
    End If

End Function

Function getWorkbook(wkbName As String) As Workbook
    
    Dim hWinXL As Long
    hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    
    Do While hWinXL > 0
                
        If getXLApp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
            For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
                If wb.Name = wkbName Then
                    Set getWorkbook = wb
                End If
            Next
        End If
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Loop
    
End Function
```

Above code is based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004179/show-all-hidden-instances-of-excel). You can test it with

```
Sub TestIt()

    Dim wkbName As String
    wkbName = "WorkbookName.xlsx"

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = getWorkbook(wkbName)
    
    If wkb Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Not open"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Open"
        wkb.Close False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help ! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. This code returns <Can't find DLL entry point FindWindowExA in user32> as the functions are also blocked by my antivirus software :/